# Unable to load the OpenModelica FMU in Python with OMSimulator

Tags: python-3.x, openmodelica

I created the FMU using OpenModelica-V1.22.1. Unable to load the FMU in Python-V3.8.10 with OMSmulator-V2.1.1. It gives the error:

*error: [fmiLogger] module FMICAPI: Could not load the FMU binary: The specified module could not be found.*

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example reproducing your error and tell us on what OS you are trying to build and simulate the FMU.

Comment: I have posted the query in Github (https://github.com/OpenModelica/OMSimulator/issues/1283). The FMU and the OMSimulator binaries are not compatible.